# How do I store time in a variable?

Tags: java, datetime, time, milliseconds

One of my classes `Event` will have an instance field which is called `timeStamp`. Now, I have another class which will set the `timeStamp` according to some other algorithm which is not really relevant here.

My question is what **type** should I store this `timeStamp` in? From what I've researched so far I have the impression that it should be calculated in milliseconds and thus store it in a `double` perhaps.

Basically the `Clock` class I have simulates time in the following format : hh:mm:ss. However, since it's a discrete event simulation that I'm developing it jumps from event to event, which it determines by `timeStamp` value i.e. each event object has a `timeStamp` value which is stored in a `PrioityQueue`. So I thought about storing the `timeStamp` in the same format as the `Clock` , which I guess would involve me creating a new class `TimeStamp` that then becomes the type of the `timestamp`. Or should I just make the clock simulate time in milliseconds?

What are your thoughts on this? I'm not sure on the most efficient/clean way to implement this.

Comment: What's wrong with DateTime?  Ah, sorry, I guess I'm thinking of the [DateTime class in Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a date is stored as *milliseconds since the epoch*, you should use a `long`.

There's no need for a `double`, since you're not interested in fractions of a millisecond.

You can't use an `int` because the maximum int value is only large enough to represent approximately one month in millis.

You can get such a value like this:

`long millisSinceEpoch = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();`

Comment: and we can avoid floating comparison imprecision!

Answer (score 2):

Store the milliseconds in a `long`.

You can use the [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class in Joda Time to perform all sorts of intricacies on the resulting number.  [This overload](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) allows you to plug the milliseconds value directly into a `DateTime` object.